# How to treat a date column so as to perfom kmeans clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis

Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion

The result of this error is due to the date column in my dataset.
May i please get clarity on how i should treat my date column if i also want to include it in my dataset to perfom a kmeans clustering algorithm.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.